# Change subgraph cluster shape to rounded rectangle

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following graph:

```
digraph G {rankdir="LR"; 
node [fontname = "font-awesome"];
subgraph cluster17 {
    2 [id=2, shape=rect;color="#A4A4A4";fillcolor="white";label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR><TD>1:10</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>>, style="filled",fontsize=6,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,height=0.2,shape=Mrecord];

    2 -> 4 [id="2t4",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5];

    subgraph cluster3 {
        4 [id=4,fillcolor="#F5BDA2", shape=rect;label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
        <TR><TD>1:12</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>, style="filled",shape=Mrecord];
        5 [id=5,fillcolor="#F5BDA2", shape=rect;label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
        <TR><TD>1:13</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>, style="filled",shape=Mrecord];
        6 [id=6,fillcolor="#F5BDA2", shape=rect;label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
        <TR><TD>1:14</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>, style="filled",shape=Mrecord];
        7 [id=7,fillcolor="#F5BDA2", shape=rect;label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
        <TR><TD>1:15</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>, style="filled",shape=Mrecord];
        8 [id=8,fillcolor="#F5BDA2", shape=rect;label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
        <TR><TD>1:19</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>, style="filled",shape=Mrecord];

        6 -> 7 [id="6t7",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5]; 
        4 -> 5 [id="4t5",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5];
        8 -> 4[id="8t4",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5];
        5 -> 6 [id="5t6",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5];
        7 -> 8 [id="7t8",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5];

        label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
        <TR><TD>Loop</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>1:11</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>;
        style="filled"
        fillcolor="#EDF1F2"
        color="#028d35"

        id=3
    }

    4 -> 10 [id="4t10",color="#717070",arrowsize=.5];
    10 [id=10, shape=rect;color="#A4A4A4";fillcolor="white";label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR><TD>1:20</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>>,fontsize=6,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,height=0.2,shape=Mrecord, style="filled"];

    label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR><TD>1:9</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>>;
    style="filled"
    fillcolor="#EDF1F2"
    color="#A4A4A4"
    id=17
}
}
```

which gives the following graph:
[image]
I wanted to change the graph of the `cluster3` to a rectangle with rounded corner. I tried to insert `shape=Mrecord`, but it doesn't work. 
How can I change the shape of the cluster to a rectangle with rounded corner?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of

```
style="filled"
```

you may use

```
    style="rounded"
    bgcolor="#028d35"
```

The style [*rounded*](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#k:style) does not use `fillcolor`, but `bgcolor` instead.

Comment: The only way it worked for me was using `style="rounded,filled"`, since according to [the docs](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html): "prior to 26 April 2005, the rounded and filled styles were mutually exclusive." (which implies that they're not anymore)

Answer (score 4):

These are the valid [styles](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/) for cluster:

[image]